# Pass underscore template a json array

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I feel like this should be possible, but I can't get it to work. Basically, using underscore and jQuery I have a template, and then I have an array of objects that I want to send to the template. It looks like this:

```
var template = _.template($("script.template").html());
var jA = data.jsonArray;
$("#results").html(_.template(template(jA)));
```

I expect it to apply the template to each object in the array, but it does not work.

if I do a loop it works, but that seems like it should be unnecessary.

```
$.each(jA, function(index,value){
   $("#results").append(_.template(template(value)));
});
```

Am I missing something or do I have to do the messy loop? (jA is definitely a json array)

Thanks :)

Comment: can you add the code for the script.template tag?

Comment: jA is a JSONArray because it comes from a jQuery getJSON which parses the data as JSON. I would expect it to do the loop because if it gets a type of array it would do something different than if it got a JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to do the loop. Underscore will not automatically loop and repeatedly append the processed template simply because you fed it an array. I'm also not sure why you think it should be unnecessary--what if you had a template that specifically needed something from an indexed element in a list, like `<%= data[0] %>`?

Anyway, the loop isn't really much trouble:

```
_.each(data, function(item) {
  list.append(template(item));
});
```

Here's [a pen](http://codepen.io/cluebcke/pen/ekiLd/) if it helps.

Comment: Yeah but appends are slow so i'd have to write it all out to a variable and put the html at the end, it seems like unnecessary and i feel like it should be handled more cleanly by underscore, though I understand it's a minimalistic library.